# Python port checker - unreachable network

Tags: python, port, connect, ipv6

I need help.
Two weeks ago such code like this went without problems and tested **ports of IPv6 addresses**, but now suddenly throws **exception**:
Error: [Errno 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network.
**Code:**

```py
print "IPv4 connection..."
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect(('173.194.70.101', 80))
    s.shutdown(2)
    print "Success connection"
except socket.error as e:
    sys.stderr.write("Error: " + str(e))
    print "Cannot connect"


print "IPv6 connection..."
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET6, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect(('2a00:1450:4001:c02:0:0:0:8b', 80))
    s.shutdown(2)
    print "Success connection"
except socket.error as e:
    sys.stderr.write("Error: " + str(e))
    print "Cannot connect"
```

**Console:**

```
IPv4 connection...
Success connection
IPv6 connection...
Cannot connect
Error: [Errno 10051] A socket operation was attempted to an unreachable network
```

Comment: Do you have a working IPv6 connectivity?

Comment: What does ping say? Can you telnet to a port on the server? Sounds like routing/firewall issues.

Comment: Some firewalls have anti hammering protection. How often did you try to connect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example works for me.

The problem is that you do not have a working IPv6 connection.

Comment: I fixed it. Dont know how it is possible but teredo tunnel adapter was missing.